# Is there any modeling on who would be the Condorcet winner in the French Presidential election?

Tags: presidential-election, public-opinion, france

The French Presidential elections use FPTP with a run off round, so directly determining the Condorcet winner is obviously impossible. But I wonder if pollsters have done any modeling to determine the Condorcet winner based on polls where voters are allowed to rank their chosen candidates or perhaps a head-to-head comparison of all the major candidates?

I’m interested in both the current election and the last few Presidential elections.

Comment: An experimentation was conducted in 2017 with 37000 participants and 4 alternative voting methods, results are available on https://vote.imag.fr/results/online